# Are there number systems with fractional or irrational bases?

Tags: number-systems

I'm wondering if there are number systems with bases other than integers? For example, with a fractional, imaginary, irrational, transcendental basis, or with the basis "infinity"? If there are, then how is the translation made in and between them?

Comment: What should the digits be in such a system ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sure. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems). The way to produce the positional representation of a number is the same as always, division with remainder. You divide the number $x$ by the base $b$ and get $g,r$ such that $x=bg+r$ and $0\leq r<b$. Then $r$ is the first digit from the right. Dividing $g$ again you get the next digit, etc.

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_base_of_numeration) is a more specific link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this example ... in $\mathbb C$, take base $-1+i$ with digit set $D := \{0,1\}$.  Numbers of the form
$$
\sum_{k=0}^K a_k (-1+i)^k,\qquad a_k \in \{0,1\}
$$
are the [**Gaussian integers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) .  And numbers of the form
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^K a_k (-1+i)^k,\qquad a_k \in \{0,1\}
$$
give us all of $\mathbb{C}$.  And the "fractions" for this number system
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} a_k (-1+i)^k,\qquad a_k \in \{0,1\}
$$
form the fractal known as the [**twindragon**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194788/on-the-boundary-of-the-twindragon).